# Media players (vlc, spotify and windows media player) don't work after a virus attack

Tags: malware, virus, virus-removal

I just got attacked by a couple of viruses while my laptop was completely unprotected. I installed the necessary programs and tried to get most of the symptoms to go away. I also think I deleted most of the malicious files both with the antivirus and manually.
Now everything seems quite normal on my computer but for one thing: I cannot play music or videos with VLC, Spotify or WMA. For Spotify the songs just skip after one second without making any sound whatsoever, WMA says it can't play file, while VLC just counts the seconds without producing any sounds. I still play YouTube videos and the likes but I can't figure out what the problem is with this stuff.

Comment: What antivirus are you using? Beyond a complete wipe and reinstall, there isn't much you can do for a compromised system that will 100% guarantee complete removal.

Answer (score 1):

The standard advice we give on recovering from a malware infection is "[nuke it from orbit](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQyCkwAGoVChMI0e2pjeiRyAIVAZcUCh2EDAcL&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DaCbfMkh940Q&usg=AFQjCNGGo7bVLRfizWK05q2XL2CTlI1PGw&sig2=eQHxeWialb18gur0jR5ocQ)". By which we mean wipe the computer, reinstall the Operating System and Software from known good copies (such as a CD or a download from the vendor) and then very carefully restore your data from backup.

The reason this is the standard advice is that modern malware is usually modular. The first bit of malware gets in, and then it installs a range of other pieces of malware. So even if your AV reports that it has removed the original infection it detected, you can't be sure that other malware has been installed that the AV hasn't found.

It might not actually be remaining malware that is causing your current issue (I suspect it more likely that the malware or the AV's cleanup has damaged some files, probably a codec.) But you can only be sure with a complete reinstall of your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest the "[nuke it from orbit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q)" approach (just to be sure). But first, you could first use [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/restore-system-files-and-settings) in order to recover the media files, then boot any *NIX distribution, mount the windows drive, recover the media files on a separate drive, check for possible malware, make a clean install of windows and finally restore your media content from the respective drive.